# ansible and virtualbox without vagrant

Tags: ansible, virtualbox

for some time I have tried to run vagrant and it worked well with ansible. However the images work completely different from images created manually. Even it looks like ssh, network, shared folders etc are slightly different configured and can only be used in the vagrant tool chain. 
So I would like to only have ansible and virtualbox on the host and use the same ssh connection for ansible as for the user
Any hints, roles, examples on how to do that (google is not a help here)

here is a short example (so maybe it is possible) if ansible could wait for the vms to be started !?

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: list VMs
      shell: VBoxManage list vms
      args:
        executable: /bin/bash
```

Comment: if you want to use ansible without vagrant, you need to install your vms and give them one static ip and in ansible you need to use the static inventory

Comment: ok thanks I'll arrange that, I hoped for some role or example playbooks